# Drag menu from bottom of the UIView

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiview, uiviewanimationtransition

I am working on iOS app, I need to implement the following functionality, 
[image]

User should drag the menu from bottom by swipe up and also it can close the menu by swipe down,

Is there any api or any class in iOS to do such functionality,
I searched it but i did not get any of such api to do it easily.
Please suggest me the solution, 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to build this your self, you can use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to recognize the drag gesture.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check this out [Code for PullableView](https://github.com/crocodella/PullableView)

UIView subclass that implements pullable behaviour similar to the Notification Center in iOS 5.

how it looks - [image: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/pullableview]

Comment: Thanks ices_2, this link will really help me.

Answer (score 0):

if your subview is at (0, 470, 320, 80) and you want to move it to (0, 400, 320, 80);
try this simple code

```
            [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.2];

            self.my_subview.frame=CGRectMake(0, 400, 320, 80);

            [UIView commitAnimations];
```